# displaying info box

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i display a 3d kind of info box giving info of a point when the mouse pointer comes over it.I want to implement something like that in google maps,the info box comes out as we move our mouse on the marker.

Thanks in advance..

You can see an example here .
http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3438/3723675824_d2f4527175.jpg

Comment: Please show a graphical sketch, it's not possible to imagine what you want

Comment: Sorry if its not clear.. I m making a map on page and i want a message box to display information of particular place on the map as soon as mouse moves over it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a tooltip in jquery ready to use:

http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2

Answer (score 0):

For each 'marker', have a 'mouseover' event that calls a function that relocates, changes the text content of, and displays an absolutely positioned div.

```
obj.addEventListener('mouseOver', showTooltip(obj.id), false);

function showTooltip(obj) {
  getDiv();
  setContent();
  positionAndDisplay();
}
```

That's just a rough idea.